# How to make #radio-1-label with img within .myClass display:none; until #radio-2-label?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Beginner attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://josephpetitti.com/blog/how-to-toggle-styles-on-click-in-pure-css) on toggling styles on click for pure css.

For label `#radio-1`, I put it in my `.bar` with an image inside it so that once `#radio-2-label` was checked, you could go back to `#tab-one` by clicking/checking the image in label `#radio-1`.

It works perfectly, however, I wanted the `img` inside label `#radio-1` to change when `#radio-2-label` and label `#radio-3` is checked.

#### Code

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="bar">
            <label class="tab-heading" for="radio-1"><img src="IMAGE1"></label>         
        </div>

        <div class="tab-parent">
            <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="tabs" checked>               
                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-one">           
                    <p>I am one.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="tabs">
                    
                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-two">
                    <p>I am two.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="tabs">
                <label class="tab-heading" for="radio-3"><h4>Info</h4></label>

                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-three">
                    <p>I am three.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
    </div>

</body>
```

Css is the same as the tutorial with some minor adjustments and the sizing of `.bar img` of course

```
div.tabs-parent {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

input[type=radio], div.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

div.tab-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  background-color: #005377;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

label.tab-heading {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3f2073;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

label.tab-heading h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

label.tab-heading:hover {
  background-color: #4ea5d9;
}

label.tab-heading#radio-2-label {
  border-left: 2px solid #1f0053;
  border-right: 2px solid #1f0053;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background-color: #005377;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ div.tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

I'm trying to think of ways to accomplish this but don't know how to execute or have a lot ideas on how to do this. For example, one idea I have is making the label for `#radio-1` `display:none;` until `#radio-2-label` is clicked and the original IMAGE2 with a lower `z-index` so the `img` in `#radio-1` appears on top and hides it.

If have any better ideas, I'd love to hear it. I know this would probably much simpler if I used javaScript, but I'm still learning js and want to be able to understand the code I'm writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the css variable and the background image:

- Put the `--url` variable inside the `.container`
- Replace the img tag in `<label class="tab-heading" for="radio-1">` with `<span class="img-1"></span>`
- Then every time `#radio-2` or `#radio-3` checked, change the `--url` variable

Hope this can help you. And also thank you about this interesting question :)

```css
.container {
        --url: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688355791542-3bc6eb957fe9?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1369&q=80");
}

.img-1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: var(--url) center/cover no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container:has(input[type="radio"]#radio-3:checked, input[type="radio"]#radio-2:checked) {
    --url: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1687223739562-ad9bc5f876fc?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1364&q=80")
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="bar">
                    <label class="tab-heading" for="radio-1">
          <!-- Change the code here -->
          <span class="img-1"></span>
          </label>         
        </div>

        <div class="tab-parent">
            <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="tabs" checked>               
                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-one">           
                    <p>I am one.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="tabs">
                    
                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-two">
                    <p>I am two.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="tabs">
                <label class="tab-heading" for="radio-3"><h4>Info</h4></label>

                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-three">
                    <p>I am three.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
    </div>
```